# Finding expectation and variance for particular problem

Tags: probability

I was solving this problem and I am not one hundred percent sure is my reasoning right. 
On each of 57 cards is 8 of 57 symbols. Each symbol is on exactly 8 cards. Each pair of cards have exactly one common symbol, and each pair of symbols is on exactly 1 card. We take 17 of 57 cards. Let $X$ be number of symbols which aren't on our cards. What is $E(x)$ and $Var(X)$? Give upper bound of probability that on our 17 cards is each of 57 symbols.

And this is what I got

Let $I_i = 1$ if i-th symbol is not present on our cards and $I_i = 0$ otherwise. $E(X) = E(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{57}I_i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{57}E(I_i)$, $E(I_i) = \frac{\frac{40!}{(40-8)!}}{\frac{57!}{(57-8)!}} = \frac{40!49!}{32!57!} = \frac{37}{795}$ so $E(X) = 57\cdot \frac{37}{795} = \frac{703}{265}$. $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$, $E(X^2) = E\bigg( \big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{57}I_i\big)^2\bigg) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{57}{E(I_i^2)} + 2\sum\limits_{i \neq j}{E(I_{ij})} = E(X) + 2\sum\limits_{i \neq j}{E(I_{ij})}$.
$E(I_{ij}) = \frac{40 \cdot \frac{39!}{(39-7)!}\cdot \frac{32!}{(32-7)!}}{57 \cdot \frac{56!}{(56-7)!} \cdot \frac{49!}{(49-7)!}} = \frac{1729676}{948485615}$, $\sum\limits_{i \neq j}{E(I_{ij})} = \binom{57}{2}E(I_{ij}) = \frac{394366128}{135497945}$.
$E(X^2) = \frac{703}{265}+2\frac{394366128}{135497945} =
\frac{229637059}{27099589}$

$Var(X) = \frac{229637059}{27099589} - \big(\frac{703}{265}\big)^2 = \frac{51573616758}{35906955425}$

Let Y be number of symbols that are on our 17 cards. I guess $E(Y) = 57 - E(X) = 57-\frac{703}{265} =\frac{14402}{265}$ , so from Markov's inequality $P(Y \ge 57) \le \frac{E(Y)}{57} = \frac{14402}{265\cdot 57} = \frac{758}{795}$.

Comment: You might find more people willing to answer if you gave your results in terms of decimal numbers to a few significant digits instead of exact rational numbers.  Few people have the patience to deal with fractions where the numerator and denominator are 12-digit numbers.

Comment: I understand that! I just want to see whether the setting is correct, not the calculation itself.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have done looks correct to me, although I have not checked your arithmetic in detail.  However, have you considered using Chebyshev's inequality in the last step?  It might give you a stronger result.  Notice that since $Y -\mu \ge a$ implies $|Y -\mu| \ge a$,
$$P(Y-\mu \ge a) \le P(|Y-\mu| \ge a) \le \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$$
for any $a>0$, and $Y \ge 57$ if and only if $Y-\mu \ge 57 - \mu$.